# Wicket Spring Hibernate Transactional

Tags: hibernate, spring, wicket, transactional

I have the following problem.
Within my wicket application i want to use @Transactional annotations.
All my DAO's are loaded with the @Component annotations ;

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public class AccountHibernateDataAccessHelper implements
    AccountDataAccessHelper
{
@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveOrUpdate(T dataObject)
{
    try
    {
        Session session = getSessionProvider().getSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(dataObject);
    }
    catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        String message = "Failed to batch save or update " + dataObject;
        log.error(message, e);
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <R extends T> List<R> list(Class<R> class1)
{
    Asserts.assertNotNull("class1", class1);
    try
    {
        return createCriteria(class1).setCacheable(true)
                .setCacheRegion(getQueryCacheRegion()).list();
    } catch (HibernateException e)
    {
        String message = "Failed to get a list of" + class1;
        log.error(message, e);
        throw new DataAccessException(message, e);
    } catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        log.error(e.toString(), e);
        throw new DataAccessException(e);
    }
}

}
```

My AccountDataAccesshelper implements the following interface

```
public interface DataAccessHelper<T>
{
public Serializable save(T dataObject);

public void saveOrUpdate(T dataObject);

public void update(T dataObject);

public void delete(T dataObject);

public void evict(T dataObject);

}
```

Next my apllicationcontext.xml settings.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="nl.response.webapp" />
<context:annotation-config />

    <!-- hibernate session factory -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="nl.response.responseframework.app.ResponseAnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="wtxwebapp" />
            <entry key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.query_cache_factory"
                value="nl.response.responseframework.service.InvalidatableQueryCacheFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                value="nl.response.wtxwebapp.core.hibernate.WtxWebAppEhCacheRegionFactory" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value="hibernate-" />
            <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
            <entry key="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

   <bean id="mainDataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" ref="hibernate.connection.driver_class" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" ref="hibernate.connection.url" />
        <property name="username" ref="hibernate.connection.username" />
        <property name="password" ref="hibernate.connection.password" />
        <property name="poolName" ref="hibernate.connection.username"/>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriodInMinutes" value="60" />
        <property name="idleMaxAgeInMinutes" value="240" />
        <property name="maxConnectionsPerPartition" value="50" />
        <property name="minConnectionsPerPartition" value="5" />
        <property name="partitionCount" value="2" />
        <property name="poolAvailabilityThreshold" value="10" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="4" />
        <property name="statementsCacheSize" value="50" />
        <property name="releaseHelperThreads" value="3" />
        <property name="serviceOrder" value="LIFO" />
    </bean>

<bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="mainDataSource" />
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

The session provider provides a session as followed

```
public Session getSession()
{
    getSessionFactory().openSession();
}
```

when i use the above session methode nothing is committed and with a huge batch i get an error since the connections arent closed properly.

When i use getSessionFactory.getCurrentSession() i get the following error

> createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

What am i missing? im trying to get this working for days already, im getting out of options :S

Comment: I get the 'createCriteria is not valid without active transaction' error when im loading a list of entitys

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a new `Session` every time you call `getSession()`.

Try this instead:

```
public Session getSession() {
    SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(getSessionFactory(), true);
}
```

This will get the Spring-managed hibernate session, created on-demand, instead of just opening a new one every time.

Note that, if you don't use [OpenInViewSessionFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html) or some equivalent, you'll still create a new session for every query, unless you are inside a transaction. But this time, Spring will close them automatically for you.

Comment: +1 it solved my problem with my DAO unit tests not being able to evict() the object that was just saved